# Wikidata normalized quantity values - how to get them?

Tags: sparql, wikidata

```
CONSTRUCT {?s ?p ?o.} WHERE { VALUES ?s {wdv:ef140324d710e935d9acbbcb30484e6d} ?s ?p ?o.}
```

returns several triples including:

```
"subject" : {
        "type" : "uri",
        "value" : "http://www.wikidata.org/value/ef140324d710e935d9acbbcb30484e6d"
},
"predicate" : {
        "type" : "uri",
        "value" : "http://wikiba.se/ontology#quantityNormalized"
},
"object" : {
        "type" : "uri",
        "value" : "http://www.wikidata.org/value/03de855c397e421300a7556187e35011"
}
```

but I don't understand how to construct a similar query for to get that normalized value. I'm sad to say I've looked at [Wikibase/Indexing/RDF Dump Format](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikibase/Indexing/RDF_Dump_Format) and still don't get it. To be clear, I'm looking for a standalone CONSTRUCT query when the value (03de855c397e421300a7556187e35011) is already known. Or maybe I do understand and there's just no node, because:

```
CONSTRUCT {?s ?p ?o.} WHERE { VALUES ?s {wdv:03de855c397e421300a7556187e35011} ?s ?p ?o.}
```

doesn't error or anything like that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You do understand, and that node has no properties. I don’t know why. Looks like a problem in the data to me. There are lots of quantityNormalized values that don’t have any properties. But there are also lots that *do* have properties and for which your query would succeed.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm really confused now because [query.wikidata.org](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Felev%20%7B%0A%20%20wd%3AQ4558%20p%3AP2044%2Fpsn%3AP2044%2Fwikibase%3AquantityAmount%20%3Felev%20%3B%20%20%23%20normalized%20height%0A%7D) returns a metric result (4392.4728) rather than feet. Is the:
`p:P2044/psn:P2044/wikibase:quantityAmount`
part of that query directing some kind of on-the-fly normalization? [Q4558](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q4558) is the entity the triples in my initial comment are associated with, if that isn't clear.

Comment: Ok, I'm less confused now. I think there's no normalized value for ef140324d710e935d9acbbcb30484e6d, but there is a parallel value-normalized statement for Q4558 which points to 17ac6762db5858eea4aa8790362efd4a, so this is the correct query:
`CONSTRUCT {?s ?p ?o.} WHERE { VALUES ?s {wdv:17ac6762db5858eea4aa8790362efd4a} ?s ?p ?o.}`